# BMS and PCB battery cells

Tags: pcb

I want to make a battery pack for my electric bike from protected PCB cells NCR 18650b, that's 24v, 13.6 Ah. My question is: Do you need to add the appropriate BMS to this battery pack since the cells themselves already have protection against overcharge and minimum discharge.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a BMS is mandatory to manage the balancing between cells in series. It would be useful to see the protection PCB circuit.